Element Plus Dropdown functions
I'm trying to attach custom functions to each dropdown item.
<el-dropdown-menu>
       <el-dropdown-item @click="editarTenant(props.row.id, props.row.domain)">Editar Información</el-dropdown-item>
       <el-dropdown-item @click="editarCampos(props.row.id)">Editar Campos</el-dropdown-item>
       <el-dropdown-item command="delete" divided>Eliminar</el-dropdown-item>
</el-dropdown-menu>

My problem is the following:
I want to pass information about each item, and using Oruga I could, but seems impossible to me.
Is this possible?

"Is it possible?".  To pass params to functions?  It's just standard JavaScript.  You are already passing props.row.id and props.row.domain to a function named editarTenant.  Do the params exist?  Does the function exist?  If so, it should work. It's not clear what the problem is.
